# Llamar función de una clase

Tags: python

tengo una clase que es llamada por un archivo inicial, según lo siguiente:

```
class coche:
# propiedades
def __init__(self):
    self.marca ='BMW'
    self.modelo = ''
    self.color = 'rojo'
    self.puertas = 3    

def estilo():
    if coche.puertas == 3:
        coche.modelo = '520i coupe'
    elif coche.puertas  == 5:
        coche.modelo = '520i'
    else:
        coche.modelo = '520i familiar'
    return coche.modelo

def arrancar():
    if coche.marca == 'BMW':
        print 'Esto es un BMW'
```

La instanciación la realizo así:

```
from myClass import coche
clase1 = coche
print (clase1.arrancar())
```

Me podéis ayudar a ver qué estoy haciendo mal, ya que me devuelve el siguiente error:

[image: Terminal]

Gracias a todos.

Comment: Hola David, mirate la pregunta del enlace de duplicado y mi repuesta a la misma. Deberías llamar mediante coche.arrancar() pero el problema principal es que tus métodos deberían ser métodos de instancia dado que modifican atributos de instancia. Es decir `def arrancar(self):` y luego en vez de `coche.marca` debe ser `self.marca`. Lo mismo con el método `estilo`. También te falta el paréntesis a instanciar `clase1 = coche()` Por otro lado, por convención los nombres de las clases deben empezar con mayúsculas y con estilo "camel-case" (`EstaEsMiClase`).  Si tienes alguna duda comenta, un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario, ahora funciona perfectamente.
Saludos